# How to query the last value for each of multiple attribute values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails and PostgresQL

I have this query for finding the last value in a table with a specific device attribute value that works great:

```
Positions.where(device_id: 3).last
```

However, now I need to query for the last value for each of multiple devices. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this more efficiently than calling the last for each device value separately.

How can I combine this:

```
Positions.where(device_id: 3).last
Positions.where(device_id: 5).last
Positions.where(device_id: 23).last
```

I've tried searching here and in the documentation. I've read and tried some 'group' and 'having' methods, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this update..

```
device_ids = [3,5,23]
Positions.where(device_id: device_ids).group(:device_id).maximum(:id)
```

It returns a `Hash`, to get the `Position` records, you can

```
device_ids = [3,5,23]
last_positions = Position.where(id: Positions
                         .where(device_id: device_ids)
                         .group(:device_id)
                         .maximum(:id).values)
```

Comment: I tried the query and received the following error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "positions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: what is the sql it generates?

Comment: `SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."deviceid" IN (3, 5) GROUP BY deviceid, positions.id HAVING (positions.id = MAX(positions.id))`

Comment: ok, I didn't have access to proper data to try out the query, check the updated answer, it works for me..

Comment: This worked! Thank you, the only edit I would make is that Positions should be Position.